# Flex Layout issues on android

Tags: react-native

Why does the following Button not work on android?

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <View style={{height:50}}>
             <Text>if this is here, the button will not work</Text>
          </View>

          <View>
            <Button
                title="Confirm"
                onPress={() => alert('click')}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

When I remove the top view, the button works. (no problems on ios)

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View>

          <View>
            <Button
                title="Confirm"
                onPress={() => alert('click')}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Its working for me on android

Comment: try using the prop `color="black"` on the button to see where is the clickable part of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the part, I posted does work. The cause for my problem was nesting it from another (parent) view.